# "list index out of range" in Python when referencing list in if statement

Tags: python

This is part of a program in Python that reads through a file, word by word, and counts instances of unique mail ID's from all lines that begin with 'From'. To achieve this, I make a list of all words in one line and go line by line to read through the list entry 0. If it is From, it adds its entry to a dict(). But I cannot reference the list entry 0 using word[0] which is my list, as it gives me that error.

I tried to use len(word) to find out whether the list has a valid length. It does. Additionally, when I print word[0], it prints normally. The traceback only happens when I'm using it in the if statement and also when referencing it in .get() in the next line.

```py
name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)
table = dict()
word = []
for line in handle:
    word = line.split()
    if word[0] is 'From':
        table[word[1]] = table.get(word[1],0) + 1
    else: 
        continue
```

I get "IndexError: list index out of range on line 8" which is the if statement

Comment: `if word[0] is 'From':` doesn't do what you think it does, you want to use `==` for comparison. That line can be fixed with `if word and word[0] == 'From'`. But I think your error probably comes on the line _after_ that, since you then try to access `word[1]` and there's nothing in your post to suggest that `split()` gives a list with more than one element

Comment: Can you provide the example input file dataset?

Comment: @roganjosh in the file I am using it on, every line that does start with From has more than one element. And I did try == before, it gives the same output

Comment: And what about at the end of the file? Are you sure that there isn't a blank line at the end?

Comment: @dimon222 https://www.py4e.com/code3/mbox-short.txt

Comment: Typically, you might have just got empty line or end of file (last line in file is empty). If you add condition `if word:` to wrap your checks for 'From' you might be able to eliminate this. On top of this, avoid using `is` for this use case, and consider using `==`. It may not be the case for this problem, but it might give a wrong result in other cases of working with strings.

Comment: @roganjosh using if word and word[0] worked. I don't get the traceback anymore. I will see if it works correctly now

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you split an empty line `word` is set to an empty list.
When you try to access any index of an empty list you get an 'list index out of range' error

try this code instead

```
name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)
table = dict()
for line in handle:
    word = line.split()
    if word and word[0] == "From":
        table[word[1]] = table.get(word[1], 0) + 1
    else:
        continue
```

Since an empty list is False I've added an check for that.
Also since python uses short circuiting for boolean operations, it will NOT check for the remaining boolean operations when it finds the answer for the operation.

This means `word[0]` will never be executed in `word and word[0]` when word is False  (a False value 'and' anything is always False).
If you invert those operations you're going to experience the same problem you had before.

A minor detail: you don't need to initialize `word` before the loop, so I've removed that line.